# How to send variable data from one html page to another? Shopping cart issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
// clicking button on page 1 and collecting all the info into variables (title, price, imageSrc)
// this part works fine

function addToCartClicked (event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    console.log(title, price, imageSrc)
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
}

// then I want this function to append the variables after element with class 'cart-items' on page 2
// however, this fucntion only allows me to append to a element with class 'cart-items' on page 1 

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.innerText = title + price + imageSrc
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
}
```

I am trying to make a shopping cart. I have two html pages sharing the same js page.

In page 1, there are items with information like price, title, and imageSrc. I then want to append this data to another page in the shopping cart.

I am successfully capturing the information when I press the item button, but I am falling at appending the data to the other html page. It seems I can only append it on the same page of the items.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `window.localStorage` to share the data between the pages. Save all data you collect by `localStorage.setItem('cart', cartData)`, then use `let cart = localStorage.getItem('myCat')` to get the data.

Check more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

Comment: Thanks! This is the type of guidance I needed.

Comment: It’s nothing. @Matthew You could mark this question is answered to let other people know it's done.